# Half-half cross-validation with logistic regression: is there a rule of thumb for whether resampling is needed?

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

I need to perform a logistic regression. The paper "Cross-Validation for Selecting a Model Selection Procedure" ([pdf](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Eyangx374/papers/ACV_v30.pdf)) seems to suggest that the best method for feature selection is repeated-sample (they perform 400 repetitions) half-half cross-validation (CV), and for model evaluation is leave-one-out CV. However, I have a very large dataset (63 thousand observations). I have read that the larger the dataset, the less we should worry about overfitting. Thus, my questions are:

1. Can I just be satisfied with performing half-half CV once?
2. Is there a rule of thumb linking the dataset's size with the number of repetitions or, more generally, the complexity of the model-selection (and possibly of the validation) procedure?

   I suspect that if such a rule of thumb exists, in the case of logistic regression it should take not only the global sample size, but also the minimum number between events and non-events into account (as it is the case with the number of parameters that makes sense to include in a logistic regression).

Edit:
Thanks Harshit for your reply. The reason why I want to compare different models is not that I want to drop the variables that have a coefficient very near to zero, but that I want to choose among different versions of the same variables, i.e.: whether including a continuous variable as it is or as a binary variable (using the median as cut-off), and which version of categorical variables to include (i.e., whether grouping variables in just 2 categories or more). Thus I don't think Lasso regression makes sense in my case.

Comment: Categorizing continuous variables is generally not a good idea.  Much better is to use a spline and choose the location or number of the knots with cross validation.

Comment: Thank you. The point is that I have several variables, so I can't focus too much attention on a single one, and would have the complication of having to condition on the choice made on the other covariates. I was thinking at exploring the 8 possibilities (2x2x2) deriving from the three variables that I need to decide how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to atleast go with CV=3 for the evaluation of your model. 
Or you can just split your dataset into testing and training set in the ratio of 70:30 which implies that 70% of the data will be treated as training and rest as the testing set.
For the feature selection using logistic regression you can use Lasso and ridge regularization as well.